# How get previousSibling and nextSibling

Tags: php, html-parsing, web-scraping

I have html:

```
<hr>
<p><font face="AvantGarde Bk BT" style="font-size: 9pt" color="#66FF33">
(08/04/2006) Parallel Worlds are one of the featured artists in the
<a href="http://www.urband.net/radio/">Urban D radio</a>. there you can listen 
to many tracks from the 3 released cd albums.</font></p>
<hr>
```

I need get

1: `(08/04/2006) Parallel Worlds are one of the featured artists in the`

2: `. there you can listen to many tracks from the 3 released cd albums.`

I use http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net.

I get element `$e->href` this is `<a href="http://www.urband.net/radio/">Urban D radio</a>`

Comment: `$font_content = preg_match('/<font face="AvantGarde Bk BT"[^>]*>([\s\S]+?)</font>/', html)`
`$text = preg_replace('/<a[^>]+>[^<]*</a>/', '', $font_content)`

Comment: @Aamir Adnan, NO! I just got myself do not use regular expressions

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_traverse

Then click 'Traverse the DOM tree'.

Comment: Hu? You asked how to get previousSibling and nextSibling, and it says how to right there on the page I linked.

Comment: I need 50 character previous and after

Comment: Get the entire node using the code in the documentation, then use substring functions on the result to trim it to 50 characters.